# Подсчет в массиве со случайными числами четных и нечетных

Tags: массивы, c

Можно ли улучшить данную программу?

Для начала юзер вводит количество чисел. Массив заполняется случайными числами. Затем программа их выводит по 10 чисел в строке. Подсчитывает четные и нечетные числа. И выдает результат.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    const unsigned short length = 0;
    unsigned short x = 0, even = 0, odd = 0; /*even - четный, odd - нечетный */

    printf("Enter the number of properties: ");

    if(scanf("%hu", &length) == EOF) {
        puts("\nError while entering numbers!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned short arr[length];

    while(x < length) arr[x++] = rand() % 10;

    puts("\n= = = = = Output = = = = =\n");

    for(x = 0; x < length; x++ ) {
        printf("%4hu%c", arr[x], (x % 10 == 9 || x == length-1) ? '\n' : ' ' );

        (!(arr[x] % 2 || arr[x] == 0)) ? even++ : odd++;
    }

    printf("\nall number: %hu, even: %hu, odd: %hu\n", length, even, odd);

    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли как-то оптимизировать код, например, вывод чисел, подсчет четных/нечетных чисел и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Проверку на четность можно делать так же путем логического "И" числа с единицей. Если получилось 1, то число нечетное, 0 - четное. например число 3 в бинарном виде: 011 & 001 = 001. Такая махинация работает быстрее оператора %.

Comment: @wwvv, "Такая махинация работает быстрее оператора %." -- готов поспорить, что x % 2 и x & 1 работают одинаково быстро.

Comment: @dzhioev, а давайте :) У меня получилось что на 4000_000_000 итерациях оператор "%" проигрывает примерно на 2 секунды (на моей машине) :Р

Comment: @wwvv: Вы специально включили деоптимизацию? Скомпилируйтесь в Release. И запускайте тест вне IDE.

Или вы тестировали получение остатка не от деления на 2? Тестовый код и опции компилятора в студию.

Answer (score 3):

- Изменять константную переменную length нельзя.
- Определяйте переменные как можно ближе к месту их первого использования. Счетчики цикла прямо в if: `if (int x = 0; x < length; ++x)`
- Массив arr не нужен. С тем же успехом можно генерить новое число на каждой итерации во втором цикле.
- x++ -> ++x.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы просто считал только нечетные.

Очевидно, что `even = length - odd`. А можно и печатать прямо в том же цикле.

```
  for (x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    odd += ((arr[x] = rand() % 10) & 1));
    printf("%4hu%c", 
           arr[x], 
           (x % 10 == 9 || x == length-1) ? '\n' : ' ' );
  }
  even = length - odd;
  printf("\nall number: %hu, even: %hu, odd: %hu\n", length, even, odd);
```

**Обновление**

В gcc -O3

что такой

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  odd += rand() % 2;
```

что такой

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  odd += rand() & 1;
```

код, превращаются в один и тот же цикл

```
.L4:
        call    rand
        addl    $1, %r13d
        andl    $1, %eax
        addl    %eax, %r12d
        cmpl    %ebx, %r13d
        jl      .L4
```

на ассемблере (для 64 бит i5-2500).

Comment: @wwvv, тест в студию.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

1) Для чего запись

```
(!(arr[x] % 2 || arr[x] == 0)) ? even++ : odd++;
```

?

Это *типа прикольно* в одну строчку? Крутизна не должна мешать читаемости кода; в серьёзных проектах за нечитаемый код, написанный без существенной на то причины, по головке не погладят. Оставьте сложный код для реально сложной логики, где без него не обойтись.

Пишем проще и понятнее:

```
if (!(arr[x] % 2 || arr[x] == 0))
    even++;
else
    odd++;
```

Далее, в условии `if`'а проверка на чётность? Выражение `arr[x] % 2` есть true (не-ноль) тогда и только тогда, когда `arr[x]` имеет ненулевой остаток при делении на 2, т. е., нечётное. Зачем вторая проверка? Вы относите ноль к нечётным числам?

Итого:

```
if (arr[x] % 2)
    odd++;
else
    even++;
```

2) Затем, цикл

```
while(x < length) arr[x++] = rand() % 10;
```

которым вы заполняете массив, тоже излишне неидиоматичен. Почему не использовать понятный всем цикл `for`?

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < length; x++) arr[x] = rand() % 10;
```

Заодно мы избавились от двух несвязанных действий в одном statement'е, чем улучшили понимаемость кода. И сделали переменную локальной.

3)

```
const unsigned short length = 0;
...
scanf("%hu", &length)
```

Это undefined behaviour. Модифицировать константы **нельзя**.

4) `odd` и `even` — не очень хорошие названия переменных. Глядя на них, не очевидно, что в них *количество* чётных/нечётных элементов. `count_odd` и `count_even` было бы гораздо лучше. Кстати, достаточно считать лишь `count_odd`, т. к. `count_even == length - count_odd`.

5) Я бы разделил ввод, основную функциональность и вывод. А то у вас в одном цикле вывод массива и подсчёт количества элементов. Это не оптимизация, это отсутствие структуры программы.

6) Вывод в случае ошибки надо бы отправлять в stderr, а не stdout.

7) И наконец, вместо проверки результата scanf() на EOF лучше написать:

```
 if(scanf("%hu", &length) != 1) {
    fputs("\nError while entering numbers!\n", stderr);
    if (feof(stdin))
      fputs("Unexpected EOF\n", stderr);
    else if (ferror(stdin))
      fputs("Unknown input error\n", stderr);
    else {
      char ebuf[10];
      scanf("%9s", ebuf);
      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid data: [%s...]\n", ebuf);
    }

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

поскольку EOF возвращается только при конце ввода **до первого** преобразования по формату или **ошибке ввода-вывода** (редкое в реальной жизни явление), а вовсе не при невозможности преобразовать какой-то текст в число.

Comment: @avp: ответ почему-то ушёл в коллективное достояние (я наверное случайно поставил птичку), поэтому имеет смысл добавить код прямо в ответ.

---
Или в ваш ответ (только сейчас его увидел).

Comment: @VladD, дополнил Ваш (теперь общий), тут это лучше смотрится.

А мой ответ сначала был парой комментариев, которые как-то начали жить своей жизнью...

Comment: @avp: спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема не в недостаточной оптимизации, а в ее избыточности. Причем ровно там, где не надо. А где надо - нету. Например, совершенно непонятно, зачем использовать printf для вывода неизменяемой строки, можно же puts. Если Вы думаете, что short чего-то там сильно сэкономит, то глубоко заблуждаетесь. Указатели имеют тип int (точнее, столько же бит).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fill_array(int* arr, size_t siz)
{
    while( siz-- ) {
        *arr++ = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void print_array(int* arr, size_t siz)
{
    while( siz-- ) {
        printf("%d ", *arr++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

size_t input_length(void)
{
    static char buf[6]; // максимум пятизначное число
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    return strtoul(buf, NULL, 10);
}

int count_odds(int* arr, size_t siz)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while( siz-- ) {
        counter += *arr++ & 1;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t length = input_length();

    if( length == 0 ) {
        puts("Incorrect length!");
        return 1;
    }

    int* array = (int*) malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    fill_array(array, length);
    print_array(array, length);

    size_t odds = count_odds(array, length);
    printf("all = %u, evens = %u, odds = %u\n", length, length - odds, odds);

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```